# How to load a class dynamically using classLoader

Tags: java, classloader, javassist

I have a .class file in disc. I want to load it dynamically onto jvm using javaassist. but it throwing exception. The following is the code i wrote:

```
ClassPath cp=new ClassClassPath(ExampleImpl.class);
    System.out.println(cp.find(ExampleImpl.class.getName()));

        System.out.println("ExampleImpl.java");
        System.out.println(ExampleImpl.class.getName());
        System.out.println();
    CtClass ctClasz = pool.get("***D:\\ExampleImpl***");
    ctClasz.addInterface(pool.get(MyInterface.class.getName()));
```

There is a .class file on the D: drive and evn it is throwing the following exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" javassist.NotFoundException: D:\ExampleImpl
at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:436)
at javaassist.Demo.main(Demo.java:24)
```

How to load a .class file on the disc dynamically onto jvm and execute it???

Answer (score 0):

Here is something without Eclipse, I think this should work (with minor modifications)

```
    Class<?> clazz;
    try {
        clazz = Demo.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("full.package.name.to.MyClass");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No such class.");
        return;
    }

    MyInterface worker;
    try {
        worker = (MyInterface)clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.out.println("Error creating actual implementation.");
        return;
    }
```